# requests.get returns <!doctype> instead <Response>

Tags: python, parsing, url, request, python-requests

I have an issue with requests.get().
If I paste the URL manually into the code as here:

```
r = requests.get('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Igelsteig-12557-Berlin.html')
print(r)
```

I get: `<Response [200]>`. Which works quite fine.
Instead if I try to ask for the requests out of a list of files as in:

```
indir = '/home/d/Desktop/civiv_hacking/Streetnames/dump/berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
  for z in filenames:
     x = urlparse.urljoin('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/', z+'/'),
     [t[0] for t in x],
     print(t),
     for r in requests.get(t):              
        print(r),
```

I get: `https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Igelsteig-12557-Berlin/ <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" xml:lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

How can I make requests.get() return `<Response [200]>` instead of just the doctype information?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the [`Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) *string representation*, you should not be iterating over it, just print:

```
url = urlparse.urljoin('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/', z)
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)  # would print "<Response [200]>"
```